# Python scalar value error during for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have got the pandas dataframe as this below:

[image: Dataset]

I would like to convert currency if it's other then PLN.
To do that i wrote the code :

```
def convert_currency():
   lst = []
   for i in risk['AMOUNT']:
       if risk['CURRENCY'].item() == 'EUR':
           lst.append(i * eurpln['EURPLN'][0])
       elif risk['CURRENCY'].item() == 'USD':
           lst.append(i * usdpln['USDPLN'][0])
       elif risk['CURRENCY'].item() == 'CHF':
           lst.append(i * chfpln['CHFPLN'][0])
       elif risk['CURRENCY'].item() == 'GBP':
           lst.append(i * gbppln['GBPPLN'][0])
       else:
           lst.append(i)
   return lst
```

but just after i tried to run this function i got the value error:

> ----> 4         if risk['CURRENCY'].item() == 'EUR':

> ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar

Could You please help me find the reason of this problem and also the resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here [no loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002) are necessary.

For performance use `map` by dictionary and then multiple by `AMOUNT` column:

```
d = {'EUR':eurpln['EURPLN'][0], 'USD': usdpln['USDPLN'][0],
     'CHF':chfpln['CHFPLN'][0], 'GBP': gbppln['GBPPLN'][0]}

risk['AMOUNT'] = risk['CURRENCY'].map(d).mul(risk['AMOUNT'], fill_value=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is not important or small DataFrame use `iterrows` for looping:

```
def convert_currency():
   lst = []
   for _, row in risk.iterrows():
       if row['CURRENCY'].item() == 'EUR':
           lst.append(i * eurpln['EURPLN'][0])
       elif row['CURRENCY'].item() == 'USD':
           lst.append(i * usdpln['USDPLN'][0])
       elif row['CURRENCY'].item() == 'CHF':
           lst.append(i * chfpln['CHFPLN'][0])
       elif row['CURRENCY'].item() == 'GBP':
           lst.append(i * gbppln['GBPPLN'][0])
       else:
           lst.append(i)
   return lst
```